# How to find a string in a binary file?

Tags: c++, file, binary-data

I want to find a specific string "fileSize" in a binary file.
The purpose of finding that string is to get 4 bytes that next to the string because that 4 bytes contains the size of data that I want to read it.

The content of the binary file like the following:

[image]

The same string in another position:

[image]

Another position:

[image]

The following is the function that writes the data to a file:

```
void W_Data(char *readableFile, char *writableFile) {
    ifstream RFile(readableFile, ios::binary);
    ofstream WFile(writableFile, ios::binary | ios::app);

    RFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    unsigned long size = (unsigned long)RFile.tellg();
    RFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    unsigned int bufferSize = 1024;
    char *contentsBuffer = new char[bufferSize];

    WFile.write("fileSize:", 9);
    WFile.write((char*)&size, sizeof(unsigned long));
    while (!RFile.eof()) {
        RFile.read(contentsBuffer, bufferSize);
        WFile.write(contentsBuffer, bufferSize); 
    }
    RFile.close();
    WFile.close();
    delete contentsBuffer;
    contentsBuffer = NULL;
}
```

Also, the function that searches for the string:

```
void R_Data(char *readableFile) {
    ifstream RFile(readableFile, ios::binary);

    const unsigned int bufferSize = 9;

    char fileSize[bufferSize];
    while (RFile.read(fileSize, bufferSize)) {
        if (strcmp(fileSize, "fileSize:") == 0) {
            cout << "Exists" << endl;
        }
    }
    RFile.close();
}
```

**How to find a specific string in a binary file?**

Comment: You're going to need to use [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp) if you want to compare your char array with a string literal without casting anything to `std::string`. `fileSize == "fileSize:"` will not work like you expect.

Comment: Not sure what the actual question is.

Comment: Note that reading the file in 9 byte chunks and then comparing assumes the string `"fileSize:"` is aligned on a 9 byte boundary.

Comment: Use `grep -a filesize`

Comment: @scohe001: I have used `if (strcmp(fileSize, "filesize:") == 0)` but it doesn't work as I expected.

Comment: @SergeyA: My question as in the title, in short, there is a string in a binary file how to find that string. that's it.

Comment: @LionKing what doesn't work as expected? That comparison? Or your program? Have you run this through a debugger?

Comment: @scohe001: That condition doesn't print "Exists" word as in the code.

Comment: Okay...but is that because your comparison is broken? Or because your `fileSize` variable is never equal to `"filesize:"`? Reread [G.M.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029064/how-to-find-a-string-in-a-binary-file?noredirect=1#comment98701854_56029064).

Comment: @LionKing Note that `std::strcmp` expects a null terminated string, which does not seem to be you case.

Comment: Looks to me like your code is checking for the string in buffers equal to the length of your stream?  Which would skip over the string if it is not aligned with your buffer increments?

Comment: @Amadeus: I have put it '\0', and the condition is not met.

Comment: @G.M.: Sorry, but your comment is not clear to me. Do you mean 9 bytes is smaller than what it required?

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560124/searching-for-a-string-in-an-input-stream.

Comment: Use `grep` or the `strings` command.  No need to write another program.

Comment: I am not good at binary. Why a binary file will has printable string? I meet a similar case and dont know how to handle it using python.

Comment: I meet some part like this using with open (filename, mode='rb') as file :   and file.read() contains sth like this: Width\x02\x01\x19DateTimeFormat\x06\x08d-MMM-yy\x15 , for example, why the English letter is not translated to \x54 for T in Time .

Answer (score 3):

I think of using [find()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) is an easy way to search for patterns.

```
void R_Data(const std::string filename, const std::string pattern) {
    std::ifstream(filename, std::ios::binary);
    char buffer[1024];

    while (file.read(buffer, 1024)) {
        std::string temp(buffer, 1024);
        std::size_t pos = 0, old = 0;

        while (pos != std::string::npos) {
            pos = temp.find(pattern, old);
            old = pos + pattern.length();
            if ( pos != std::string::npos )
                std::cout << "Exists" << std::endl;
        }
        file.seekg(pattern.length()-1, std::ios::cur);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the seekg part should be seekg(1-pattern.length(), std::ios::cur);   Suppose we try to find '1234' in 'AAAA1234AAAA', and the read buffer size is 6.

Answer (score 1):

> How to find a specific string in a binary file?

If you don't know the location of the string in the file, I suggest the following:

1. Find the size of the file.
2. Allocate memory for being able to read everything in the file.
3. Read everything from the file to the memory allocated.
4. Iterate over the contents of the file and use `std::strcmp`/`std::strncmp` to find the string.
5. Deallocate the memory once you are done using it.

---

There are couple of problems with using

```
const unsigned int bufferSize = 9;

char fileSize[bufferSize];
while (RFile.read(fileSize, bufferSize)) {
    if (strcmp(fileSize, "filesize:") == 0) {
        cout << "Exists" << endl;
    }
}
```

#### Problem 1

The `strcmp` line will lead to undefined behavior when `fileSize` actually contains the string `"fileSize:"` since the variable has enough space only for 9 character. It needs an additional element to hold the terminating null character. You could use

```
const unsigned int bufferSize = 9;

char fileSize[bufferSize+1] = {0};
while (RFile.read(fileSize, bufferSize)) {
    if (strcmp(fileSize, "filesize:") == 0) {
        cout << "Exists" << endl;
    }
}
```

to take care of that problem.

#### Problem 2

You are reading the contents of the file in blocks of 9.

First call to `RFile.read` reads the first block of 9 characters.
Second call to `RFile.read` reads the second block of 9 characters.
Third call to `RFile.read` reads the third block of 9 characters.  etc.

Hence, unless the string `"fileSize:"` is at the boundary of one such blocks, the test

```
if (strcmp(fileSize, "filesize:") == 0)
```

will never pass.

Comment: "Read everything from the file to the memory allocated" - or just memory map the file...? Seems simpler to me.

Comment: I have updated my code `strcmp/strncmp ` doesn't find the string.
Another thing, The file may be too large in Gigabytes, so, I think It will be a bad way if I copy entire content to the memory to find the string.

Comment: @LionKing, that won't work unless the location of the string is divisible by 9.

Comment: "the location of the string is divisible by 9", sorry but can you explain this point in detail?

Comment: @LionKing "text filesize: othertext". You will read in "text file" and then "size: oth". Though I'm not sure if your code is even safe since I'm not familiar with RFile and don't know if it's null terminating the buffer. Doesn't look like it since "filesize:" is 9 bytes. If it's not terminated, that would also cause it to never find the match.

Comment: Thank you, but is there a solution for "the boundary of one such blocks" problem?

Comment: @LionKing, I hesitate to say there isn't a solution but I can't come up with anything that is easy to understand and code.